# How to remove pin name from Eagle Device Page? [See Image]

Tags: pcb, schematics, eaglecad, layout

How to remove those pin name from Eagle Device Page?

[image]

Comment: That page shows just the symbol …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to symbol page
2. Right click on pin
3. Select properties
4. In 'Visible' dropdown select 'pin'
5. Click OK and save

Answer (score 1):

That's easy to do! You'll want to pull up the **Symbol Editor** for that.

*Quick clarification: You can't use the "Device Page" to edit symbols and based on what's circled in red on your image, you're asking to delete the pad labels, not "pin name[s]".*

1. Right-click on your part and at the bottom of the menu select "**Open Symbol**" to pull it up.

[image: Open Symbol Menu Item]

2. In the Symbol Editor right-click again the tip of the pin and select **"Properties"**. This will bring up the editor for one pin. Later you'll want to do this for each pin. And you may want to use the "Group" selection tool if you have a lot of pins.

[image: Symbol Menu]

3. Change the "**Visible**" option from **"both"** to **"pin"** to get the result you're looking for. Setting Visible to "pin" may seem backward at first. Below is an explanation for that.
4. Save the symbol, close the Symbol Editor, and select Library > Update All to update your schematic with the changes you made to the part in your library.

[image: Symbol Editor Property Window]

The pin labels are on the inside of the schematic symbol's rectangular box. So why are pad labels on the outside? It's better to think of the pad labels as if you are just about to drop it on your board and you are wondering how it should line up. Since ***pads*** are the small copper surface the ***pins*** of the part connect to they're shown this way in the schematic view at the end of the pin where you'll connect the net.

I made the following graphic (based on yours) to help clarify further:

[image: Eagle "Pads" vs. "Pins"]